# Is the software for the server of https://snapcraft.io/ closed or open source?

Tags: ubuntu, snap, open-source

I keep hearing different things from different people, some people are telling me that the reason people don't like snaps is because the software that runs the server for https://snapcraft.io/ is closed source and proprietary.

Other people are telling that everything including the software for https://snapcraft.io/ is 100% open source and that everything in snaps is 100% open source.

I don't know what or who to believe, so I wanted to post this question here and see if it can get resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's a mix of open-source and closed-source software.

For example, Slack is closed-source but LibreOffice is open-source.

But looking at the store I'd say there's more open-source software. I would have to research each project to confirm that. If that's what you are after, you could research each snap before you install it.

Answer (score 1):

> some people are telling me that the reason people don't like snaps is because the software that runs the server for https://snapcraft.io/ is closed source and proprietary (...) Other people are telling that everything including the software for https://snapcraft.io/ is 100% open source

I think the question here is whether is Open Source any snap you may download from the Snap Store, not the Snap Store server software itself.

And the answer is that the Snap Store doesn't bother about licensing. It's up to the creator of a particular snap to decide how to license their program. So you can find and download snaps that are Open Source as well as closed source.

From [their About page](https://snapcraft.io/about):

> Snaps can bundle both proprietary applications and open source. If you build proprietary software you can use the “Proprietary” license. For open source projects we support SPDX expressions so you can let your users know exactly what license your project uses.

From [their ToS](https://ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/snap-store-terms):

> 6.3 If your Snap includes open source software, you will comply with all applicable open source software licence requirements. Nothing in these terms limits or grants rights that override any open source software licence terms.